# Cannot find default.realm file under data/data path

Tags: android-studio, react-native, realm

I'm using Realm and React Native to build an Android app. I want to open .realm file with Realm Studio. I opened "Device File Explorer" from Android Studio and saw the default.realm file under "projectName/files/" (See screenshot #1).
But the folder was empty if I opened that path. (See screenshot #2)

For now, I have to work it around by saving this file to another place and opening the newly saved file from Realm Studio (See screenshot #3). Very strange. Why is the path folder empty?

#### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pull from device to your my documents.

Directly you cannot access it. But You can try with an older Android version, it will work there.

[image]